# Scala - how to validate every String in list using Validated monad from cats?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a list of `Strings` which I need to validate if they are match some pattern:

```
def validate(strings: List[String]): Either[WrongStringError, List[String]] = {
    strings.foreach(s => checkString(s))
    Right(strings)
  }

private def checkString(s: String): Validated[WrongStringError, String] = {
  val pattern = .... //some regex
  Either.catchNonFatal(s.matches(pattern))
    .left
    .map(_ => WrongStringError(s"Given string: ${s} is not valid."))
  }.toValidated
```

But, what I want to achieve is to accomulate all errors together. If for example 3 of 5 strings are incorrect I want return error with them to the user. I thought of using `Validated` monad from `cats` but I did not get result.
How can I validate list of strings and return list of errors for those which are incorrect?

Comment: Validated is not a monad, it is applicative - you can `map` it or calculate product of two validated values, but you cannot `flatten` it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought of using Validated monad from cats but I did not get result.

Well, the idea of things like `Validated` *(or any FP data structure)* is to compose values together.

However, you are not composing anything here, you are just calling a `foreach`, so in case of a failure you would not even receive the errors, you will always receive a `Right`.

Also, if you want to collect all errors, you would need to use some kind of *(non-empty)* container like `NonEmptyChain`.

Finally, this common pattern of I have a collection of values and a function that transform those values into an effectual value and I would like to collect / combine all those effects into a single effect of a list is called `traverse`.

Bonus points, this common pattern of using an isomorphic effect type that looks exactly like my normal effect just that it is only an `Applicative` instead of a `Monad` in order to provide a different *(parallel)* behaviour is so common, that **cats** introduced the `Parallel` typeclass and combinators *(e.g. `parTraverse`)* to avoid the boilerplate.

In any case, this is how the code would look like:

```scala
import cats.data.NonEmptyChain
import cats.syntax.all._

type Error = String

def validate(strings: List[String]): Either[NonEmptyChain[Error], List[String]] =
  strings.parTraverse { s =>
    checkString(s).toEitherNec
  }

def checkString(s: String): Either[Error, String] = {
  val pattern = ""
  Either.cond(
    test = s.matches(pattern),
    right = s,
    left = "Given string: ${s} is not valid."
  )
}
```

---

BTW, I would recommend you to study more about FP.
I may recommend you the talk "Functional Programming with Effects" by Rob Norris and the *(free)* book "Scala with Cats".